# Android WebView issue, Please use a fully capable web browser such as Google Chrome to access this site

Tags: android, android-webview

My app use the web view and today when i want to load a webpage it shows this message: Please use a fully capable web browser such as Google Chrome to access this site.

does anyone has any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: It will do tomorrow if you dont have questions.

Answer (score 0):

try below user agent string for your webview.

```
public static String getDefaultUserAgentString() {
    String version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    String id = Build.ID;
    String chromeVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 24 ? "58.0.3029.96" : "70.0.3538.77";
    String safariVersion = "537.36";
    return "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android " + version + "; " + Build.MODEL + " Build/" + id + ") AppleWebKit/"
            + safariVersion + " (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/" + chromeVersion + " Mobile Safari/" + safariVersion;
}
```